# 'Could not find schema information for the element 'application'

Tags: schema

I get the error mentioned in the topic.

My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.runtime.remoting>
     <application>
       <service>
         <wellknown type="SimpleRemotingAsm.RemotingMessageObject,SimpleRemotingAsm" objectUri="RemoteMsgObj.soap" mode="Singleton"/>
       </service>
       <channels>
         <channel ref="http"/>
       </channels>
     </application>
   </system.runtime.remoting> 
</configuration>
```

I've read MANY thread regarding the problem, but nothing helped me at all.

I am using VS .NET 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio allows you to associate multiple DTD (Document Type Definition) files with your App.config or Web.config files. The fix for this problem is kind of wonky:

1. Open your Visual Studio solution
2. Open the config file for editing
3. Right-click on the config file's filename in the Solution Explorer pane
4. Click "Properties"
5. Now click back on the editor pane for that config file
6. The "XML Document" Properties should be visible in the Properties pane
7. The "Schemas" property contains a space separated list of `.xsd` file names that provide XML element definitions for your config file. You will need to click the `...` button in the value field for this property and browse to the proper XSD file. Once you've added it, the "Could not find schema information..." warning should go away when you build the solution.

As for where the XSD file is? I'm not sure. The [Remoting Example: Hosting in Internet Information Services (IIS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2swb8ah%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) documentation might be a good place to start.

Comment: I have had luck using: http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd although it has a copy write date of 2008 which makes me slightly nervous.